# How do nature photographers find agents?

Tags: marketing, business-plan

A friend of mine has been working on a project to build a data base of plants native to where she lives.

The problem is that it has become difficult for her to continue the project on her own.

I was helping her blog the pictures; and that has yielded some good results. So far, there are over one hundred thousand views.

She understands that she can self-publish. The problem with that is it pulls her even further away from what she’s good at doing.

Another idea she and I have talked about is partnering with a botanist and writer, but that costs money she doesn’t have.

Which got us thinking

- What kind of agencies represent nature photographers? And
- What’s important to them with a photographer?